# Is using enums in Flutter expensive as using them in Android?

Tags: android, flutter, enums

I'm currently working on a project where i use `enums` to avoid `string literals` which will:

- make changes a little bit easier
- simplify some return statements.

But i have read from a while ago that google discourages using enums in android development.

> Google discourages the use of enums on Android app development as stated on their developer guidelines: "Enums often require more than twice as much memory as static constants. You should strictly avoid using enums on Android."

So when it comes to `Flutter`, **is it the same case?** or, **are there some concerns about using lots of enums in Flutter?**

Comment: `google discourages using enums in android development` how sure are you this is still true ?

Comment: For Android at least, "Enums are fine": https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/when-using-enums-and-r8-3f8f314c0a13

Comment: Flutter enums are just ways of organizing compile-time constants that have strong typing.  They don't consume any more memory than writing "6" everywhere (which compiles to reference the same singleton "6", if not inlined).